# Manipulate object using cURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl

Included below is a sample of the data found in the file `1.php`:

```
: [
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "active": "1",
        "wait": "30"
    },
    {
        "ID": "6",
        "active": "1",
        "wait": "10"
    },
    {
        "ID": "8",
        "active": "1",
        "wait": "65"
    }
]
}
```

This is my code so far, and I'm not getting very far so any help appreciated.

```
<?php
$url = "1.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);  

if((date("H") < 9) || (date("H") > 24)) {
    echo "Closed";
} else {
    echo ($Queue_Time: <= 10) ? $data : $Queue_Time-5;
};
$result = json_decode ($json);
$arr = array(1, 2);

?>
```

Basically, I would like to display "ID":"1" as a name, such as "Meat" "ID":"2" "Cheese" etc. Then display a queue wait time which is the value of "wait" next to the name.
The shop is only open from 10am-5pm so outside of these hours I just want it to display the name and "Closed" next to it insead of the wait time.

Lastly if the wait time is greater than 10 mins, then I would like to deduct 5 mins from that value.

I am unable to get the code above to work as expected and would really appreciate a hand.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken a few liberties in trying to get what you want, so let me know how close it is:

```php
// Assuming we have a correctly formatted JSON array from CURL
$data = '[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "active": "1",
        "wait": "30"
    },
    {
        "ID": "6",
        "active": "1",
        "wait": "10"
    },
    {
        "ID": "8",
        "active": "1",
        "wait": "65"
    }
]
';

// This array maps IDs to Names
$department[1] = 'Meat';
$department[2] = 'Cheese';
$department[6] = 'Fish';
$department[8] = 'Vegetables';

// Decode the JSON data
$data = json_decode($data);

// Loop through each area
foreach ($data as $counter) {
    // Check if closed
    if((date("H") < 10) || (date("H") > 17)) {
        $queue = "Closed";
    } else {
        $queue = ($counter->wait <= 10) ? $counter->wait : $counter->wait-5;
    };
    // Output name and wait time
    echo $department[$counter->ID].' '.$queue.'<br />';

}
```

Comment: Many thanks , this works in principle. This is working great with the test data: $data = '[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "active": "1",
        "wait": "30"
    },
    {
        "ID": "6",
        "active": "1",
        "wait": "10"
    },
    {
        "ID": "8",
        "active": "1",
        "wait": "65"
    }
]
';
However I'm trying to capture the data from 1.php using curl_init(); when I delete the test data it doesn't read the values from 1.php
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a full URL for $url? You can't just use a filename. You can also check if CURL gives an error using [curl_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Comment: This is my amended code, as I say it works perfectly with the test data you provided, just not with Curl, however i'm probably just not calling it correctly: http://towerstimes.co.uk/queue/2.php, I'm getting: 
'Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/towerstimes/public_html/queue/1.php on line 6' using the code above

Comment: can you send me an email chris@towerstimes.co.uk and I will give you details its kind of confidential. Credits will be given to you on the site if we can get this working

Comment: Thankyou so much John, if I had 15+ reputation I would vote you up as you provided exactly what I was looking for.
Thanks again.